# I need a TAG field solution

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a web-based application that uses PHP and MYSQL. It is a kiosk application that sits in multiple stores that sells many of the SAME products. (IE - bagel, juice, ice cream, etc.) Each of my stores are listed in MYSQL table called "**tblstores**" and each product is listed in a table called "**tblproducts**".

What I would like is in each Product record, I want to TAG which stores that product will be listed on my kiosk application.

A similar example would be how I submit this question on Stack Overflow and it let me TAG with keyterms that are related. EX: For this question I will use PHP, MYSQL, HTML. I would like the TAG options to be STORES in my tblstores table.

Comment: Assuming some products can be in many stores, I'd probably intoduce an additional table, something like "products_to_stores" that would hold a product id and a store id. It's difficult to elaborate further without seeing the actual database structure

Comment: This is a many-to-many relationship and is probably best represented using an additional table as @Eihwaz suggested. This will make the relationship between stores and products much more manageable.